# Are all ant routing algorithms the same?

Tags: algorithm, swarm-intelligence, ant-colony-optimization

Are all ant routing algorithms the same? If no, what is the common properties of all of them? In other words, how we can detect a routing algorithm is an ant routing algorithm?